# SpringBoot @KafkaListener got MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from A to B

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, avro

I am using SpringBoot 2.7.5 got an issue which the @KafkaListener got the MessageConversionException. The whole error logs show below:

```
Bean [example.package.api.kafka.HelloKafkaListener@30e312a2]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot handle message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [example.packageapi.ExampleEvent] to [example.packageapi.ExampleEvent] for GenericMessage [payload={"exampleField": "HELLO WORLD"}, headers={kafka_offset=37, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@3bb288b4, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=my-topic, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1678197991282, kafka_groupId=my-topic:HelloKafkaListener}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={"exampleField": "HELLO WORLD"}, headers={kafka_offset=37, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@3bb288b4, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=my-topic, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1678197991282, kafka_groupId=my-topic:HelloKafkaListener}]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot handle message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [example.packageapi.ExampleEvent] to [example.packageapi.ExampleEvent] for GenericMessage [payload={"exampleField": "HELLO WORLD"}, headers={kafka_offset=37, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@3bb288b4, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=my-topic, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1678197991282, kafka_groupId=my-topic:HelloKafkaListener}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={"exampleField": "HELLO WORLD"}, headers={kafka_offset=37, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@3bb288b4, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=my-topic, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1678197991282, kafka_groupId=my-topic:HelloKafkaListener}]
```

The consumer configurations:

```
consumer:
  group-id: my-topic:HelloKafkaListener
  auto-offset-reset: latest
  key-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
  value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
  properties:
    spring.deserializer.key.delegate.class: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
    request.timeout.ms: 5000
```

The versions I used are:

```
<confluent.version>7.3.0</confluent.version>
<avro.version>1.11.1</avro.version> 
<spring.kafka.version>2.8.10</spring.kafka.version>
```

My pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-client</artifactId>
    <version>${confluent.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
    <version>${avro.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
    <version>${confluent.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-streams-avro-serde</artifactId>
    <version>${confluent.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

My event.avsc is like this:

```
{
  "namespace": "my.name.space",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "ExampleEvent",
  "doc": "A sample event",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "exampleField",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

I use the confluent tool send the message in the terminal like this:

```
    ./kafka-avro-console-producer \
    --broker-list localhost:59092 --topic my-topic \
    --property schema.registry.url=http://kafka-schema:80 \
    --property value.schema="$(cat ~/codebase/avro/event.avsc)"
    {"exampleField":"HELLO WORLD"}
```

And if using the `./kafka-avro-console-consumer` to get the message, it works well.

My listener is like this:

```
public class HelloKafkaListener {
  private final HelloKafkaService helloKafkaService;
  
  @Autowired
  public HelloKafkaListener(HelloKafkaService helloKafkaService) {
    this.helloKafkaService = helloKafkaService;
  }
  
  @KafkaListener(
      topics = "my-topic",
      groupId = "my-topic:HelloKafkaListener"
  )
//  public void process(ConsumerRecord record) {
//    log.info(record.value().toString()); // it works: {"exampleField": "HELLO WORLD"}
//  }
  public void process(@Payload ExampleEvent event) {
    this.helloKafkaService.handleMessage(event);
    log.info("Processing event: " + event.getExampleField());
  }
}
```

If I use `ConsumerRecord record`, it works I can see the `record.value().toString()` is `{"exampleField": "HELLO WORLD"}`, but switch to `ExampleEvent event`, it throws exception. Anyone knows why this happens? Many Thanks!

Thank you for the help! After reviewing the comments, I created a `DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory` and `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` like this:

```
@Bean
  public DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, ExampleEvent> helloConsumerFactory(
      @Value(value = "${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}") String bootstrapAddress,
      @Value(value = "${spring.kafka.properties.schema.registry.url}") String schemaRegistryUrl
  ) {
    var props = Map.<String, Object>of(
        ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress,
        ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId
    );
    var keyDeserializer = new ErrorHandlingDeserializer<>(new StringDeserializer());
    var config = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    config.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryUrl);
    config.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, true);
    var jsonDeserializer = new KafkaAvroDeserializer(null, config);
    var valueDeserializer = new ErrorHandlingDeserializer<>(jsonDeserializer);

    var factory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(props, keyDeserializer, valueDeserializer, false);
    
    return factory;
  }
  
  @Bean
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ExampleEvent>
  helloKafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConsumerFactory<String, ExampleEvent> helloConsumerFactory) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory helloContainerFactory =
        new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    helloContainerFactory.setConsumerFactory(helloConsumerFactory);
    return helloContainerFactory;
  }
```

Updated Listener:

```
  @KafkaListener(
      topics = "my-topic",
      groupId = "my-topic:HelloKafkaListener",
      containerFactory = "helloKafkaListenerContainerFactory"
  )
//  public void process(ConsumerRecord record) {
//    log.info(record.value().toString()); // it works: {"exampleField": "HELLO WORLD"}
//  }
  public void process(@Payload ExampleEvent event) {
    this.helloKafkaService.handleMessage(event);
    log.info("Processing event: " + event.getExampleField());
  }
```

However, still got the same issue.

Comment: did you add the second part of my answer with containerFactory inside @KafkaListener?

Comment: Yeah, I idid. Please see the update KafkaListener above

Answer (score 1):

Check this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-kafka#2-consuming-messages). You have to provide the message converter for your custom java object `ExampleEvent`. The `@Payload` just by it self is able to receive just a `String` message.

Try with

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, Greeting> exampleConsumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
      props,
      new StringDeserializer(), 
      new JsonDeserializer<>(ExampleEvent.class));
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ExampleEvent> 
  exampleKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ExampleEvent> factory =
      new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(exampleConsumerFactory());
    return factory;
}
```

And then register this by

```
      @KafkaListener(
      topics = "my-topic",
      groupId = "my-topic:HelloKafkaListener",
      containerFactory = "exampleKafkaListenerContainerFactory"  //<-------
  )
  public void process(ExampleEvent event) {
     this.helloKafkaService.handleMessage(event);
     log.info("Processing event: " + event.getExampleField());
 }
```

Also ensure that in your dependencies you already have the following otherwise add it manually

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Given that the packages are the same, this usually means that the deserializer was loaded by a different class loader to that which loaded the listener, for example because Spring Dev Tools is being used.

Comment: So adding the deserializer like shown here should avoid it (or you can use a setter on Boot's auto configured factory).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. I tried using JsonDeserializer<>(ExampleEvent.class) but my payload is Avro format. looks like JsonDeserializer is not able to deserialize the message. but after your hint I created DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory and ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory (please see above), but still got the same error. I feel like some configuration doesn't do right with the KafkaAvroDeserializer. Any ideas again? Many thanks

Comment: Thanks again. Like @Gary Russell mentioned above, the root of the issue is spring-boot-devtools. Once I remove it, it start to work.

Answer (score 1):

> `[example.packageapi.ExampleEvent] to [example.packageapi.ExampleEvent]`

Given that the packages are the same, this usually means that the deserializer was loaded by a different class loader to that used to load the listener, for example because  Spring Dev Tools is being used.

When specified via a property, the deserializer is loaded by the Kafka clients instead of Spring.

One way to avoid that is to add the deserializer directly to the consumer factory instead of via a property. You can use the constructor or setter on the factory, as shown in the other answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly, the spring-boot-devtools issue. After I remove it, everything works fine. Just wondering is any work around to keep the spring-boot-devtools also make sure the same issue won't happen again?

Comment: The work around is, as I said, add the deserializer to the factory instead of via the property.

Comment: Thanks you, Yeah, I have updated my code (above) to add a KafkaAvroDeserializer, but once add the Spring Dev Tools back, the issue happens again. It's not a huge deal not to use the Spring Dev Tools, but just curious any better solution

Comment: I believe that adding the deserializer to the factory, instead of Kafka loading it via a property, resolved the problem for others, try running in a debugger to see which class loader is loading the class.

Comment: Stuck in the same situation as Zichen. Added this to my ContainerFactory bean but it did not help: `factory.setConsumerFactory(new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerProps(), new StringDeserializer(), new KafkaAvroDeserializer()))`. Also removed setting the deserializer in my consumer props so this is the only place where the deserializer is being declared.